# Set Layout in Rails 5 Controller Based on pg_search Query String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) and would like to conditionally set a layout template based on a query string.  Below is my index method which I know is wrong, but wanted to provide an idea of what I am trying to do.

**products_controller.rb**

```
...
def index
  if params[:query]
     if :query.include?('limestone')
        layout 'product-index-limestone'
      end
     @products = Product.search_for(params[:query])
  else
  ...
  end
end
...
```

Comment: do you want to set layout inside controller action right?

Comment: I think so yes because I have at least 2 more custom layouts I need to set for other queries. I’m still noobish at this so I am just making educated guesses at the correct path to take.

Comment: for setting layout you need to write `respond_to block inside that you need to provider format.html and then render with layout`

Comment: `respond_to do |format|
 if #condition
   format.html {render :layout => 'youquery layout'}
 end
end`

Comment: what happens? did you get anything from comments

Comment: so I understand the `respond_to` part, but I don't know how to check if query contains keyword.

Comment: `params || params[:query].present `

Comment: @uzaif I already have an outer block that checks `if params[:query]`, but  how do I create another block that specifically checks if params includes keyword `limestone`?  Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167498/discussion-between-uzaif-and-studio-rooster).

Comment: try this code
`def index 
respond_to do |format| 
if params[:query].include?("limestone") 
format.html {render :index, layout:'limestone'} 
elsif params[:query].include?("gray") 
format.html {render :index, layout:'gray'} 
end 
end 
end`

Comment: That worked!! Thank you.  Please create an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `respond_to` block in your controller action like below way and set layout within it

```
def index 
    respond_to do |format| 
      if params[:query].include?("limestone")
         format.html {render :index, layout:'limestone'}
      elsif params[:query].include?("gray") format.html 
        {render :index, layout:'gray'} 
      end # end of if
    end #end of respond_to block
end
```